# Match dates between tables with difference in date form to closest date

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I have two tables which record entry dates in the same date format `YYYY-MM-DD`

Table 1 contains an update index and all these dates are `YYYY-MM-01`, always first day of month.

Table 2 contains record entries that are in format `YYYY-MM-DD`

I want to change values in table 2 using the index value in table 1 based on the month and year.

I've tried below but this only gives the exact date match where i just need the month year matched.

`AND table1.indexdate::date = table2.recorddate::date`

Running on 9.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`date_trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC)

```
AND table1.indexdate::date = date_trunc('month', table2.recorddate::date)::date
```